# Retrieving hierarchy within table

Tags: sql, oracle

I've been working with a query to retrieve hierarchy of a file in a database. Here is an example of what the table looks like:

```
_Name_               _HierarchyPath_                
Parallel EEPROM     163796003/1761551443/413793741/1362244494/110367462/3988861187/3597067685/4208992221    
Parallel Flash      163796003/1761551443/413793741/1362244494/110367462/3988861187/3597067685/1995340606    
Parallel I-F        163796003/1761551443/413793741/1362244494/110367462/391521622/2389021280/3222611234 
Parallel I-F        163796003/1761551443/413793741/1362244494/110367462/391521622/4124681422/3222611234 
Parallel, In-line   163796003/1761551443/413793741/977119157/977119157/1065183491/4216548299/92850509/1330595286    
Serial\Parallel I-F 163796003/1761551443/413793741/1362244494/110367462/391521622/4124681422/92930422
```

So basically, I figured the last number in `HierarchyPath` is the `HierarchyID` of the object in the DB. What I need is a way to retrieve the full path of the object (meaning each number between `/` is equal to an object). I have succeeded in finding the whole path of something, but in multiple rows. I would like to have it in one row, if possible.

Here is my current query and result (for the second `Parallel I-F` in the first table):

```
SELECT *
FROM WC.CLASSIFICATIONNODE
WHERE substr(HIERARCHYID, - instr(reverse(HIERARCHYID), '/') + 1)     IN         ('163796003', '1761551443', '413793741', '1362244494', '110367462', '391521622', '4124681422', '3222611234')
ORDER BY HIERARCHYID;
```

It results in:

```
Part                163796003/1761551443/413793741
Electronic          163796003/1761551443/413793741/1362244494
Integrated Circuits 163796003/1761551443/413793741/1362244494/110367462
Data Acquisition    163796003/1761551443/413793741/1362244494/110367462/391521622
Parallel I-F        163796003/1761551443/413793741/1362244494/110367462/391521622/2389021280/3222611234
ADC                 163796003/1761551443/413793741/1362244494/110367462/391521622/4124681422
Parallel I-F        163796003/1761551443/413793741/1362244494/110367462/391521622/4124681422/3222611234
Data Acquisition    163796003/1761551443/413793741/1362244494/40756919/3258224989/2899710639/391521622
```

How can I get something like `Part/Electronic/Integrated Circuits/Data Acquisition/ADC/Parallel-I-F` ?

I'm currently trying to use a left join on the same table but no success. I also read about using CTE, but I've never been able to successfully use one. I'm on SQL developer, but don't mind other environment answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want seems possible. But I cannot completely figure out your table's structure from your (in this regard poor) description. So I will make up my own to demonstrate how this can be done. You'll have to translate that in your schema yourself.

And since you mentioned SQL Developer, I guess you're using Oracle. You also missed to tag the DBMS you're using.

The table `OBJECT` stores the objects with name and ID.

```
CREATE TABLE OBJECT
             (ID NUMBER(38),
              NAME VARCHAR2(8));
```

The table `HIERARCHY` stores paths of objects as a string of their IDs, separated by `'/'` and an ID.

```
CREATE TABLE HIERARCHY
             (ID NUMBER(38),
              PATH VARCHAR2(8));
```

Now first thing we need is a number table having integers from 1 to the maximum of objects in a path in `HIERARCHY`. We can use a recursive CTE for that.

```
WITH CTE(I)
AS
(
SELECT 1 I
       FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT CTE.I + 1 I
       FROM CTE
       WHERE CTE.I <= (SELECT MAX(REGEXP_COUNT(HIERARCHY.PATH, '/')) + 1
                              FROM HIERARCHY)
)
```

`REGEXP_COUNT(HIERARCHY.PATH, '/')` will count the occurrences of `'/'`in the path. By adding 1 to it, we get the number of objects in the path. And we want the maximum, so we wrap it in `MAX()`.

Now we can left join that CTE to all rows of `HIERARCHY`, so that each row of `HIERARCHY` occurs as often as the number of objects in the path of the row (or one time if the path is the empty string, which is equivalent to `NULL` in Oracle).

```
FROM HIERARCHY
     LEFT JOIN CTE
               ON CTE.I <= REGEXP_COUNT(HIERARCHY.PATH, '/') + 1
```

We once again can use `REGEXP_COUNT(HIERARCHY.PATH, '/') + 1` to join all numbers, that are less or equal the number of objects in the path.

`CTE.I` will now number the rows from `HIERARCHY`, for each object in the path there's one integer from 1 to the total number of integers in the path (or `NULL`, if the path is `NULL`).

We can use `CTE.I` in the result of the join to extract the object ID from the path, that is at the `CTE.I`-th position in the path. For this, we can use `REGEXP_SUBSTR()`:

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR(HIERARCHY.PATH, '(^|/)[^/]+', 1, CTE.I)
```

The pattern matches all characters, that are not a `'/'` after the beginning of the string or after a `'/'`. The fourth parameter, `CTE.I`, tells the function to return the `CTE.I`-th match. That's how we get the relevant object ID for the respective position in the path. Unfortunately there might be unneeded `'/'` at the beginning of the returned matches, so we wrap it in a `REGEXP_REPLACE()` to remove them.

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_SUBSTR(HIERARCHY.PATH, '(^|/)[^/]+', 1, CTE.I), '^/')
```

With that, we can now left join `OBJECT`. We just throw in an additional `TO_NUMBER()`.

```
LEFT JOIN OBJECT
          ON OBJECT.ID = TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_SUBSTR(HIERARCHY.PATH, '(^|/)[^/]+', 1, CTE.I), '^/'))
```

Having `OBJECT` joined we're almost done. We now `GROUP BY` the columns of `HIERARCHY` we want in the output, e.g. `HIERARCHY.ID` and `HIERARCHY.PATH`, and use `LISTAGG()` to concatenate the object names to a path separated by `'/'` again.

```
LISTAGG(OBJECT.NAME, '/') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY CTE.I) OBJECT_PATH
```

The `ORDER BY CTE.I` makes sure every object name is in the right place in the path.

All together we get:

```
WITH CTE(I)
AS
(
SELECT 1 I
       FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT CTE.I + 1 I
       FROM CTE
       WHERE CTE.I <= (SELECT MAX(REGEXP_COUNT(HIERARCHY.PATH, '/')) + 1
                              FROM HIERARCHY)
)
SELECT HIERARCHY.ID HIERARCHY_ID,
       HIERARCHY.PATH HIERARCHY_PATH,
       LISTAGG(OBJECT.NAME, '/') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY CTE.I) OBJECT_PATH
       FROM HIERARCHY
            LEFT JOIN CTE
                      ON CTE.I <= REGEXP_COUNT(HIERARCHY.PATH, '/') + 1
            LEFT JOIN OBJECT
                      ON OBJECT.ID = TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_SUBSTR(HIERARCHY.PATH, '(^|/)[^/]+', 1, CTE.I), '^/'))
       GROUP BY HIERARCHY.ID,
                HIERARCHY.PATH
       ORDER BY HIERARCHY.ID;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=8f063ca8670ff658110b0a54178f4dd1)

Comment: There is no table that shows objects and their IDs separated, I only have them with their respective path. However, I subselected those items and the query works wonderfully (better than my 7 left join hehe). Thanks a lot !